# log4j log file created but not logging data

Tags: java, log4j, jboss7.x

i am new to log4j. i saw many tutorials . to use log4j. but none worked for me.

i am using log4j in jboss 7.

the problem is file is created but log info not logged
here is my property file

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-a
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/home/latif/AutoGS.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern= %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c - %m%n
```

and the servelet in my web app is

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;


@WebServlet(name = "Helloworld", urlPatterns = {"/Helloworld"})
public class Helloworld extends HttpServlet {

final static Logger logger =     Logger.getLogger(Helloworld.class.toString());

Logger APPLICATION_LOGS = Logger.getLogger("rootLogger");

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> and
 * <code>POST</code> methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("/home/latif/NetBeansProjects/FirstLog4jExample/src/java/log4j.properties");
    try {
        APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Starting");
        APPLICATION_LOGS.info("Starting");

        logger.info("This is a logging statement from log4j");

        String html = "<html><h2>Log4j has been initialized successfully!</h2></html>";
        response.getWriter().println(html);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("###### This is debug : " + "Hmmm  ");
        }

        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("******** This is info : " + "Hmmm  ");
        }

        logger.warn("This is warn : " + "Hmmm  ");
        logger.error("This is error : " + "Hmmm  ");
        logger.fatal("This is fatal : " + "Hmmm  ");

    } finally {
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

the problem is the file is created and logs are printed in the server console . but the logging information is not writing in the file.

please provide any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried using the logging subsystem instead of a log4j configuration? https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Logging+Configuration